# How can I solve problem for run container app in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Image error:
[image: show image error]

problem running container runs a few seconds and stops
I already followed other steps to do the following and it doesn't even work like that

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
```

then

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show content in your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Also, can you try running command `docker logs local_web_1` and show what it returns?

Comment: @SateeshPagolu   result --->  is not a valid port number or address:port pair

Comment: Can you show your docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Thanks  It was already solved by adding the following line to the yml   ` command: [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]`  @Sateesh Pagolu

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.